# How to reverse through list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, reverse

I have the following page which uses css & jQuery to animate list elements. It starts from the first one (top) and loops through each occurrence until they are all displayed. It uses CSS to make the elements visible.

What i am wanting to do it make it start from the bottom rather than the top of the list, so showing the last element first, and the first last. Essentially reverse the order it goes in as of now.

I understand this should be pretty simple but i'm struggling to figure it out. I presume the logic will have to be done in the loop in the script tag

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <h1>Position 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Position 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Position 3</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Position 4</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>Position 5</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<style>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

.list{
    margin:3em auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
 }

.list li{
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 72px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
    from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    }

    to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.slideInLeft {
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-duration: 250ms; 
    visibility: visible !important;
}

</style>
<script>
(function(){
'use strict'

    var items = document.getElementsByTagName('li')

    function doSetTimeout(i) {
      //console.log(items)
      var t = items[i]
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            t.className = 'slideInLeft'; 
        }, (i+1) * 1150);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
      doSetTimeout(i);

})()
</script>
```

Any advice would be appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Call `items.reverse()` before your `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently iterating through the list of `items` with:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
```

You can iterate through this in reverse by doing:

```js
for (var i = items.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. Still doing from the top down